# Using one wireless mouse for multiple computers: WoW 5 boxing

Tags: keyboard, mouse, kvm-switch

I have a friend who's wanting to five box for WoW. He's been using a keyboard/mouse switch/signal multiplier, however it has proven to be not what he needs. He was looking at getting five sets of the same keyboard/mice to use around the office, then when playing wow, hook up all the receivers to the 5 different WoW PC's. So my question is this :

Is it possible to use 5 receivers for one mouse/ 5 receivers for one keyboard if all the keyboards are using the same frequency/ all the mice are using the same frequency?

If this cannot be done, some software/hardware solutions would be great.

Comment: pro tip - if your question should _really_ be tagged "discussion" or "world-of-warcraft", just don't ask it here. If those were really good tag fits, the gaming stackexchange site would be better.

Comment: gotcha. Thanks for the tip. Still getting used to all the different exchange sites

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'll be difficult to find a particular receiver that will all listen to the same mouse/keyboard.

You might have more success trying to use mouse/keyboard sharing software like [snergy](http://synergy-foss.org/).  Have to muck with the conf file so that mouse /keyboard updates are mirrored on all screens.